# How to stop null value fields from being marshalled in Grails

Tags: json, grails, marshalling

I am using Grails 1.3.7 and have the following DTO

```
class Result {
   String key
   List errors
}
```

Now either the key or the errors will be present, but not both. If the Result has a key, I don't want the marshalled JSON to have the errors field with a null value as shown below

```
{"errors":null,"key":"abcde"}
```

I looked at [configuration options](http://grails.org/Converters+Reference) for the converter and it does not have an option for suppressing null values. I also looked at the last section on that page titled 'Customizing Converters Results' and registered an object marshaller as follows

```
class Result {

   static {
      grails.converters.JSON.registerObjectMarshaller(Result) {
     return it.properties.findAll {k,v -> v != null}
     }
   }

}
```

But still the result contains errors with the null value. I am looking for the cleanest way to achieve this for both XML and JSON.

Comment: What happens if you put this on Bootstrap instead of the domain class?

Comment: It did not make a difference. I still see the same result.

Answer (score 1):

Trying this Grails 2.0.3 results in an error indicating conflict between the `errors` field and GORM's automatically-added `grails.validation.ValidationErrors` field (also named `errors`).  Your marshaller looks OK, so you may just need to change your field name to something other then `errors`?